# Math question about polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

What i dont understand is something particular.

Suppose we have the point [3,1]. I can use an INFINITE number of combinations of r and θ in order to satisfy rcosθ=3. But incredibly,among these infinite combinations, only ONE combination of r and θ is able to satisfy rcosθ=3 **AND** rsinθ=1.

Why? ( it's a subtle math question)

Comment: You have *one* equation in *two* unknowns in the first case. You have *two* equations in the second case. Hardly surprising that the solution sets would not be the same, in this case a line vs. a single point.

Comment: i thought that : **2 variables + 2 equations = 1 unique solution** works only with linear equations ...

Comment: @Qwerto It is only _guaranteed_ for linear equations (unless you're unlucky). In the non-linear case, $n$ equations in $n$ unknowns will still generally give you a set of solutions consisting of discrete points, while fewer than $n$ equations in $n$ unknowns gives a continuum of solutions, both in the linear and the non-linear case.

Comment: "works only" not quite.

Comment: @Qwerto No, it doesn't (always) work for linear equations, either, for example $\,x+y=1, x+y=2\,$ has no solutions while $\,x+y=1, 2x+2y=2\,$ has infinitely many. Yet, counting the number of constraints vs. the number of free variables is a good starting point to assess what you are looking at, linear or not.

Comment: Thanks. What's the name of the theorem for the non-linear case. I want to read the proof :)

Comment: There is no general theorem for  $all$  types of non-linear equations. The equation $x^2+y^2=0$ has just one solution with $(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2$  but infinitely many solutions with $(x,y)\in \Bbb C^2.$  Even with just 1 variable and 1 equation, such as $\cos x=1,$ we may have infinitely many solutions in $\Bbb R. $

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $r>0$ the two equations $r \cos \theta=3,r \sin\theta=1$ are equivalent to $r^2=10, \cos\theta=3/\sqrt{10},\sin\theta=1/\sqrt{10}$. Thus there is only one $\theta\in[0,2\pi[$ and only one $r>0$ such that the two equations above are satisfies. But if you admit arbitrary $\theta$ you get countably many solutions $\theta_n=\theta+2\pi n, n\in\mathbb{Z}$. If $r<0$ were admitted, there would be even more solutions.